# Database updates from web host in android

Tags: php, android, mysql

i have a Application with a database and i want update the database from net 
i used downloading whole database and extract file in database folder but some time get wrong I'd like some advice if there is a better way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a webservice. This can be done in PHP (I also use RESTful Api's). These services will return JSON which you can parse through.

Try this out:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/